# WPF what is the equivalent of SelectedIndexChanged for a datgrid combo box column?

Tags: wpf, datagridcomboboxcolumn

How can I can an event to fire similar to selectedindexchanged with the datagridcombobox column type?

Answer (score 0):

I would think that the recommended approach in this case is not to worry about the UI element firing the changed event, but rather listening for your ViewModel's change event which will be fired when the combo box changes the bound value.

Comment: It would depend completely on your own ViewModel, but essentially you'd be listening for the INotifyPropertyChange::PropertyChanged event.